# Why do they use $\equiv$ here?

Tags: notation

I thought I had pretty much figured out the difference between $\equiv$ and $=$. Then I came across this while reading about partial derivatives (in Colley's *Vector Calculus*):
$$
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} (y^2) \equiv 0
$$
when $f(x,y,z)=x^2y+y^2z$. Why do they use $\equiv$ in stead of $=$ here?

Comment: In this case, it means "identically $0$" (that is, the value is always $0$), rather than "find a value where it is equal to $0$".

Comment: I think you can safely ignore it, just imagine it is = instead. The author may be using it in some weird way that normally isn't done.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference for the above excerpt.

Comment: @Bill: I'm very sorry for the late response. I found this in Susan Colley's *Vector Calculus*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$\equiv$ is often used (between functions) to mean they are identical (instead of being equal at some point).  in your example this means identically $0$.  if someone write something like $f(z)=g(z)$ it might be thought these functions are equal at some point $z$ instead of *every* point $z$, so you could write $f\equiv g$ or $f(z)\equiv g(z)$ to mean they are equal everywhere.

Comment: So $\equiv$ is stronger than $=$?

Comment: @Eivind: It's not "stronger" or "weaker", it's meant to emphasize that this is an equality of *functions* rather than an equality of *values* of the function. When one writes, for example, "$x^2+x = x^3+x^2$", it may be unclear if one is talking about the values of $x$ will make the two expressions equal, or if one is talking about an equality of functions (which holds, for example, if you consider the two polynomials as functions on the field of two elements). Use of $\equiv$ emphasizes that you are talking about equality of *functions*, not values. But both are statements about equality.

Comment: @Arturo: OK, that makes it clear. Thank you.

Comment: You could think about it like this: $f(x) \equiv g(x) \iff f(x)=g(x) \forall x$

Comment: I suppose my next question would be, why don't we see ≡ more often?

Comment: because with reasonable notation otherwise you dont need it and people tend to use it wrong. for functions $f,g$, $f=g$ is precisely defined as $\forall x:f(x)=g(x)$, so no need to ever write $f\equiv g$, which is how i see it abused most often. as opposed to the answer, $f(x)=g(x)$ is not an equality between functions at all, but between values, $x$ has to be bound outside of this statement.

Comment: one use case remains, i've never seen it in the wild and it is similar to $\leftrightarrow$ vs $\Leftrightarrow$ in logic, where the latter automatically universally quantifies all free variables, i.e. $f(x)\equiv g(x)$ then means $f=g$, but we have the advantage that we can use it for expressions which cannot unclumisly be written as functions, e.g. $2^{x+y}\equiv 2^x2^y$ instead of $((x,y)\mapsto 2^{x+y}) = ((x,y)\mapsto 2^x2^y)$.

Comment: see the accepted answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/when-should-i-use-and-equiv?noredirect=1&lq=1 .